# Solving a linear difference equation

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

I have to find a general solution for the difference equation given as
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + h(1 - y_n) $$ with initial condition: $ y_0 = 0$ and $h$ constant.
The solution should be
$$ y_n = 1 - (1-h)^n$$

So I first rearrange to get $ y_{n+1} = y_n(1-h) + h $ but I'm not really sure where to go from here. I can use the initial condition to get $ y_1 = h $ and further $ y_2 = 2h(1-h)$ and further again to get $ y_3 = 2h(1-h)^2 + h$, but this seems to be getting further and further from the solution I'm looking for, although I do notice the power of $(1-h)$ increasing which is encouraging. But when I expand to $y_4$ this $(1-h)$ dissapears.

I'm really not sure where to go with this question, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try to find $\alpha$ such that $y_n+\alpha$ satisfies a simpler recurrence relation?

Comment: $y_{n+1} = y_n + h(1 - y_n) \iff y_{n+1} = (1-h) y_n + h$ which is an [**Arithmetico -Geometric Progression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

Comment: $y_1=h=1-(1-h)$, $y_2=y_1(1-h)+h=[1-(1-h)](1-h)+h=1-h-(1-h)^2+h=1-(1-h)^2$. And so on by induction...

Comment: @Momo that's a clever solution, I just doubt that I would see that if I didn't know the solution beforehand.

Comment: You don't need to know the solution beforehand. It is a first order inhomogeneous [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), and there is a well-known formula to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just transform
$$
z_{n+1}=1-y_{n+1}=1-y_n-h(1-y_n)=(1-h)(1-y_n)=(1-h)z_n
$$
and proceed from there.